# VBA macro throws error when attempting to save (but only on one computer)

Tags: vba, save, runtime-error, ms-word

We have written a VBA macro for MS Word. The macro seems to work properly on my and my coworker's computer. It also works on computers of our other coworkers, but when ran on our boss' computer (all have Windows 7 as operating system) it does not.

The specific error occurs when trying to save with:

```
.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\" & userName & "\Documents\Project\" & companyName & "\" & fileName & ".docx"
```

For some strange reason it cannot save only on one system. I have checked Trust Center setting but they do not seem different. Any ideas?

*note: userName is simply a string holding the user name of the user*

Comment: What specific error is thrown? Note that you are showing the open, not the save statement.

Comment: Sorry I have mistakenly pasted the wrong line (sincere apologies!). Will edit to be correct. As for the error - I will paste tommorow as my boss is gone and the error cannot be reproduced on my computer. We have error handling so it only showed the messaged we prepared (for situations where the filename is wrong, but it should be ok in our test)

Comment: Does the affected username have a space or special character in any of the variable names? You could try wrapping the file in double quoted double quotes.

Comment: It is a letter + number so technically it does not. Beside all of our logins are the same except for different digits in the username so I doubt it's that.

Comment: Check for security issues. Does the logged-in user have permission to perform the save operation? Do the folders exist?

Comment: Are you sure the directory exists on the target machine? A better approach might be using specialfolders. Try something like: `FilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("mydocuments") & "\Project\" & CompanyName & "\" & Filename & ".docx"`

Comment: Will try tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was resolved. The problem was with the MS Office settings, specifically in the save tab, where the default save setting was set to Open Document format instead of Word Format (.docx)

Surprisingly, editing the line to:

```
.SaveAs fileName:="C:\Users\" & userName & "\Documents\Project\" & companyName & "\" & fileName & ".doc"
```

helped and made it work. However, instead of editing our macro like this, we simply switched the setting to save default in word format and since then it worked properly.
I find it surprising and quite 'stupid' that a VBA macro depends on this setting, but in case anyone encounters the same problem, changing the setting OR the extension to .doc should fix it

Comment: Your code probably would have worked correctly, regardless of the setting on the machine, if you'd also specify the `FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument` parameter, not just the `FileName`. That will override the default setting on the machine.